# Множественное к "примат" (первенство, пеобладание)

Tags: грамматика

Кузнецов к слову "примат" (в значении "первенство, преобладание") дает замечание *"только ед."*)
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82

Другие словари явно не этого указания не содержат, но и обратного не утверждают.

Помнится, однако, что в школе-институте преподаватели это множественное использовали. Можно ли всё-таки его использовать? Ну вот в такой примерно фразе. *Мы знаем о примате духа, примате разума и других. Эти приматы(?) являются предметом исследования известных философов (таких-то)*.

Если такая форма невозможна, как это сказать правильно?

Comment: Предметом исследования является не предшествование (примат), а соотношение (примат одного над другим). Так что пример мне кажется неудачным. И в целом я за единственное число. А приматы пусть живут на деревьях.

Comment: @М_Г,  фраза моя условная, просто хотелось показать, как и откуда это множественное возникает. Но с позиций философских вы ерунду сказали. Во-первых, не решайте за автора, что он хочет исследовать. ))) А во-вторых, с каких это пор и кем Гегель или там Кант лишены возможности исследовать свой собственный тезис? И в третьих, если уж вы так это понимаете, замените слово "исследуют" на "пропагандируют": *Эти приматы(?) пропагандируют Кант и Гегель.*  Как вы эту фразу с единственным числом построите?